# Error while I try to install sudo apt-get update

Tags: apt, 20.04

```
0% [Connecting to ru.archive.ubuntu.com (2a02:6b8::183)] [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (2001:67c:1562::15)]^C
```

And then it shows that there are some errors while installation.
Also, I have an error when I try to install `curl`

Comment: "some errors" is, unfortunately, too vague to offer useful advice. Please edit your question to show us complete input and output.

Comment: E: Failed to fetch http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/nodejs/nodejs-dev_8.10.0~dfsg-2ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb  Cannot initiate the connection to ru.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2a02:6b8::183). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)

Comment: Please do not comment on your own question. Edit your question instead. `101: Network is unreachable` suggests that you have a network issue, not an apt issue. Do some basic network troubleshooting.

Comment: `2a02:6b8::183` is an IPv6 address. Disable IPv6 in the System Settings -> Network-> your interface, IPv6 tab. Some system along your network path doesn't like IPv6.

Answer (score 0):

Are you still having an issue with this?

It seems like the update process is getting stuck while trying to connect to the Ubuntu.

First check your internet connection. On my experience, I have to change my server (Go to the Software & Update -> Ubuntu Software -> "Download from") to my closest location as I am not in US. I had an trouble installing certain packages as some packages requires from specific server. Maybe try to mess around with it.

If this is not an issue, try to run these (Unlock the package manager):

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install curl
```

If these does not work, please reply to this comment.